how can i solve this overflow problem on cols?
I gave 70vh height to cols.
It brokes on 3. col because of it has inside cols, it cant calculate right way to fit in. Example, I have p tag on col:nth-child(3) col:nth-child(1) but it hides.
HTML:
`
<section id="fitness-program" class="container py-5" data-aos="fade-up">
<div class="row justify-content-center gap-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col mb-4 p-5 rounded d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center hid" data-aos="fade-up" style="background: #28A745;">
        <h3 class="text-white">Start Your Fitness Journey Today with Us</h3>
        <a class="nav-link active bg-white fw-normal mx-1 px-4 py-2 rounded-pill mb-5" aria-current="page" href="#">Get Started<i class="bi bi-chevron-right ms-2"></i></a>
        <img src="assets/fitness/start.png" class="img-fluid w-75" data-aos="fade-up">
    </div>
    <div class="col mb-4 bg-dark-gray rounded d-flex flex-column" data-aos="fade-up" style="height: 70vh;">
        <img src="assets/fitness/training.png" class="img-fluid w-100" data-aos="fade-up">                
        <h3 class="mb-4 px-4">Our Expert Trainers<b> will guide you to achieve your goals</b></h3>
        <p class="px-4">Join our program and experience personalized training sessions that will help you stay fit and motivated. Our trainers are here to support you every step of the way.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col mb-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center" data-aos="fade-up" style="height: 70vh;">
        <div class="col bg-dark-gray rounded">
            <img src="assets/fitness/tracker.png" class="img-fluid w-100" style="height: 25vh;" data-aos="fade-up">
            <h4 class="text-center w-100 mb-4 px-5 py-3"><b>Track Your Progress</b><br>easily with our mobile app</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col mt-5 bg-dark-gray rounded p-4" data-aos="fade-up">
            <img src="assets/fitness/success.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I divided row to 3 column.
CSS:

.hid {
    height: 70vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#fitness-program .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
    height: 70vh; 
}

#fitness-program .col > div {
    width: 100%; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#fitness-program .col .bg-dark-gray {
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

#fitness-program .col .bg-dark-gray:nth-of-type(1) {
    height: 25vh; 
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#fitness-program .col .bg-dark-gray:nth-of-type(2) {
    height: auto; 
}


the keyword is safe , for justify-content:safe center;  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#safe

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your design, is easier to implement using a grid (rather than nested flex containers)
html
<section id="fitness-program">
  <section>…</section>
  <section>…</section>
  <section>…</section>
  <section>…</section>
</section>

css
#fitness-program {
  display: grid;
  height: 70vh;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template:
    "  a     b     c   " .70fr
    "  a     b     d   " .30fr
    / .40fr .35fr .25fr;
  > section {
    &:nth-child(1) { grid-area: a; }
    &:nth-child(2) { grid-area: b; }
    &:nth-child(3) { grid-area: c; }
    &:nth-child(4) { grid-area: d; }
  }
}

As you can see, the grid's 70vh tall, split into 3 cols (taking up: 40%, 35% and 25% horizontally) and 2 rows (taking up: 70% and 30% vertically), where areas a and b span 2 rows each.
The reason for using the fr unit (instead of %), is that: fr uses the remaining space in the container (%, is based on the parent's width/height); if we were to use %, since the grid has a gap, there'd be an overflow, 'cause the % doesn't subtract the gap's space.
